# Django filter a model in the template

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to be able to filter a model in the template (or find a different solution to fix my problem). The relevant models look like this:

```
class CommissionElection(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    commission = models.ManyToManyField(Commissie, related_name="elections")

class ElectablePerson(models.Model):
    commission = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    election = models.ManyToManyField(CommissionElection, related_name="electables")

class Commissie(models.Model):
    commissie = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Here Commissie is a model from a different app.

I have created a page for a specific election, now I want on that page a list per commission which states all the ElectablePersons that stated themselves electable for that commission (and for that election).

I tried the following in my template:

```
{% for commission in election.commission.all %}
{{ commission }}
  {% for electable in election.electables.filter(commission=commission) %}
    {{ electable}}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This gives the error

> Could not parse the remainder: '(commission=commission)' from 'election.electables.filter(commission=commission)'

Is there anyway I could filter the model in the template or is there a different way I could do this?

Comment: IMO the root of all the problems is not in weak template language here, it's in the data model. Consider to step back a little and rethink your data model. With drawing ER diagram, taking [Normal Forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) into account, virtually running add/edit/remove scenarios maybe with DFD diagrams included. If I understand correctly what you're trying to implement, I don't see why would a Commission or a Person have an M2M field. Couple of additional models could flatten down this _abstraction of abstractions_ drastically.

Comment: @IvanStarostin it has a M2M field because there will be multiple elections, which have overlapping commissions and a person can be electable for multiple commissions

Answer (score 0):

You can simply move the filter function into model definition.

```py
class Commissie(models.Modle):
    commissie = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def electables(self):
        return ElectablePerson.objects.filter(election__commission=self)
```

Then in your template, call the defined method and loop

```
{% for commission in election.commission.all %}
  {{ commission }}
  {% for electable in commission.electables %}
    {{ electables }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

———

Update: Use custom template filter

Create a templatetags directory under your app directory, and then create a electables.py file within it

```py
# app/templatetags/electables.py
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def electables(election, commission):
    return election.electables.filter(commission=commission)
```

Then in your template

```
{% load electables %}

{% for commission in election.commission.all %}
  {{ commission }}
  {{ for electable in election|electables:commission }}
    {{ election }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: the problem is that when I try to do this, I get an error that it is circular import, because Commissie is from a different app...

Comment: I see. Then you can create a custom template filter. Check update of my answer.